# One of the slave-concubines permitted... Could someone explain what this sentence means please

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-patterns

I am not a native speaker of English and I am now reading a Sci-Fi book called Dune. I am unable to grasp all the sentences but I do get the overall meaning of paragraphs. But this sentence is completely puzzling me.

> One of the slave-concubines permitted my father under the Bene Gesserit-Guild agreement could not, of course,bear a Royal Successor, but the intrigues were constant and oppressive in their similarity.

Here are my doubts:

1. The "could not" refers to the agreement or the permission by the slave-concubine?
2. The "intrigues" refer the details of the permission or the agreement?

Could someone please help. I really enjoy the book and would love to understand it better.

Comment: In this text "One of the slave-concubines permitted my father" in more simple English would read "One of the slave-concubines that my father was permitted to have"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about Dune will get a better answer at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune

Comment: @grateful: Thanks a lot grateful, that was the main thing causing my confusion. I am not familiar with that sentence structure.

Comment: @ab2: Had no idea there was a separate forum about dune, but my doubt is more regarding the sentence structure than the details of the book.

Comment: Questions which lack results of research are out of scope.
Interpretation requests are out of scope.
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Comment: @Bootstrap I hope your English questions were answered -- let me know if they were not.  Dune readers often turn into Dune fanatics.

Comment: @ab2 : Grateful's comment is really what I was looking for as he explained what that sentence would mean in plain English. I did not understand what that sentence meant. And no, please do not worry, no fanatic here.

Comment: @MetaEd : Thanks for the link MetaEd. I am new here and will definitely check that out. Based on all the comments here, looks like I should just have asked what a sentence of that structure means without any reference to Dune. Glad to see that "grateful" got what I was asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's saying that if one of the slave-concubines bore a child from a member of the royal family then that child would not be considered an heir to the royal family.  They can bear a child, but the child would not be a "Royal Successor", ie could not succeed to the throne.  The child would be a "bastard", to use the old terminology, who were not considered as legitimate heirs.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bastard_(law_of_England_and_Wales)

"Intrigues", in this context, means "things which happen that are not made public but may be of interest to some people, or manipulated by people for their own ends".  See the noun definitions here:

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/intrigue

In this case it's referring to the love affair between a member of the royal family and a concubine, and probably also various ways in which certain parties tried to exploit this for their own ends, make accusations, etc.

Answer (score 1):

> One of the slave-concubines permitted my father

"One of the slave-concubines" is the subject of the sentence whose verb is "could…" while "permitted my father" is a participial phrase modifying "one of the slave-concubines". The "my father" is a retained object from a ditransitive sentence which would look similar to:

> (Someone) permitted my father slave-concubines~.

This is in active voice, but in passive voice, it would look like:

> Slave-concubines~ were permitted my father by (someone).

In your sentence, "by (someone)" is omitted.

Comment: Thanks jasper for the grammatical explanation. But it will take me a while to grasp the intrigues of this :)